# Redirecionar um endereço com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma url x e toda vez que o usuário digitar essa url no **navegador**, quero que ele seja **automaticamente direcionado pra url y**, como fazer isso com javascript ou jQuery?

Comment: Já tentou     window.location = "http://www.algumaurl.com.br";

Comment: Para url especifica acho melhor redirecionar no htaccess... Caso o contrario se quiser mesmo fazer em js você terá que pegar a url atual, comparar se é url "X" se sim você da um window.location.href, mas para esse tipo de coisa acho melhor o htaccess

Comment: Qual a vantagem disso? Coloca o conteúdo da pagina com url y na pagina de url x

Comment: Ja encontrou solução para essa pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ window.location.href ="url y"; });
```

JavaScript

```
<body onload="window.location.href = 'url y';">
```

Answer (score 1):

Olha, amigo.
Embora seja possível, esse método de redirecionamento não é muito recomendado porque ele só é executado depois que todo o código é carregado.
Há outros métodos mais eficientes...

Com PHP:

```
header("location: https://seusite.com.br");
```

Com a metatag Refresh do HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='https://seusite.com.br'"/>
```

O Content é equivalente ao tempo de espera para redirecionar.

Com JavaScript:

```
window.location.href='https://seusite.com.br';
```

Com jQuery:

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://seusite.com.br');
```

Embora não seja necessário utilizar jQuery para redirecionar páginas.

Aí fica ao teu critério qual utilizar.